# Can I determine if an SSRS instance is tied to an SSRS database from the database?

Tags: reporting-services

I found an SSRS database and an SSRSTempDB on a SQL Server and have no idea if they are tied to an SSRS instance. Can I find the SSRS instance or servername somewhere in the database?

Comment: Open up the Reporting Services Configuration Manager and see if the database is in there.

Comment: What if the SSRS instance was installed on a separate server?

Comment: Hmm. Good point. Looking at your answer, did you figure it out with profiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the best way to determine if this db is being used anywhere is run profiler...

Comment: It's a little easier to just use activity monitor and see if any SSRS instances are logged into the database. (it will show the host name)

Comment: In the end i went with profiler. I ran it for a few hours and reasonsed that its not being used. My next step is to take the databases offline and see if anyone complains.